# Generating a dummy equals to 1 if the product was purchased in the previous period

Tags: stata

I have a panel data set with product purchases identified for unique household ids and need to generate a dummy variable "brand loyally" that will equal to 1 if the same brand was purchased by the household in the previous period. My periods are not equally timed. For some households it can be 1 week, for others - 10 weeks. Does this code sound about right?:

```
panid - unique household id
l5 - brand name
loy - wanted dummy


bysort panid week: egen loy=1 if l5=l5[_n-1]
```

Comment: You need to xtset your data and use lag operators.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that the unit of the variable week is weeks. In that case you can type

```
tsset panid week
by panid: gen byte loy = ( L.l5 == l5 ) if !missing(L.l5,l5) & _n > 1
```

Comment: Note that `by panid:` does no harm here to underline that calculations are within panel, but the lag operator ensures that any way. Similar comment applies to `_n > 1`.

Comment: @NickCox the `by panid:` is indeed superfluous, but the `_n > 1` is not. I create the indicator (dummy) variable using the logical statement `( L.l5 == l5)`. For the first observation within each panel it will return 0 (false), while I suspect it makes more sense to turn that into missing.

Comment: The user needs to decide what makes sense. But the usual argument is that we don't know what preceded the first observation, so anything about its predecessor is recorded as missing.